# IP Masquerading Mac OS X

Tags: unix, macos

I am trying to figure out how to use this command with mac os x

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

The only thing I have found that seems like it might work is

```
ipfw add m all from me to 0.0.0.0/0
```

but I get: `ipfw: invalid action m\n'`

Does anybody know how I could translate the iptable code to mac compatible code?

Comment: Why exactly do you have to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to share your internet connection, you can do this from System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing

If that's not why you posted this and you still do it manually(see Eir Nym's post). Don't forget to:

```
    sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like following. Please, read all details [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3209267?start=0&tstart=0). I hope this is working with non-server Lion (as FreeBSD nature of this OS), but I haven't tested it.

```
 ipfw add 00010 divert natd ip from any to any via (ext int name here)
 /usr/sbin/natd -config /path/to/SL/natd.conf.apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps needed to set this up. `en0` in this case is the external interface:

```
/usr/sbin/natd -interface en0
/sbin/ipfw -f flush
/sbin/ipfw add divert natd all from any to any via en0
/sbin/ipfw add pass all from any to any
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```